# C# Dev Kit - How to specify --configuration and --environment

Tags: visual-studio-code, testing, configuration, customization

I've search for two days but couldn't find a wayfor specifying the --configuration and --environment parameters when executing and debugging tests via test shortcuts and the test explorer. By using the tasks.json and launch.json configuration files I successfully configured the build and debugging process for my application. Now, I need to replicate this functionality for my test projects as well.

This is the output when I press a the play button on test me:

If I run the tests using dotnet cli on command line the tests run fine since I'm able to setup dotnet cli like below:

[vscode play button image](https://ibb.co/KrSxJ8r)

[vscode test build output](https://ibb.co/KGN6hqF)

```bash
dotnet test -c MyTest1Debug --environment MyTest1Environment
```

I'm using the latest version of vscode (1.84.2) and C# Dev Kit (1.1.16).

Thanks.

I've searched for information in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/csharp/testing, vscode github and google.